# Is there an effective genus theory for indefinite quadratic forms?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, quadratic-forms, computational-number-theory, isomorphism-testing, genus

For positive definite quadratic forms, there is a way to check if two forms are isomorphic by arithmetic equivalence over $GL_n(Z)$ by computing configurations of vector up to some norm and then checking for equivalence of those vector configurations. Similarly, we can compute the arithmetic automorphism group which is the finite subgroup of $GL_n(Z)$. See AUTO/Isom by Plesken & Souvignier and subsequent developments.

For the case of signature $(1,n)$ we can build a theory of perfect forms and check for isomorphism. This is very expensive but gives a finite algorithm for testing if two forms of signature $(1,n)$ are equivalent and give an explicit isomorphism. For the automorphism group, the algorithm that computes the perfect forms gives a side product a generating set of the automorphism group of the quadratic form of signature $(1,n)$.

For the binary quadratic form case $(1,1)$, the theory of Pell's equation provides another approach to the problem.

Now in the general indefinite case, the answer to the question is as I understand genus theory. The problem is that I would need it to be effective. That is given two forms of signature $(p,q)$, I would like to know if they are isomorphic and if so find a matrix in $GL_n(Z)$ realizing the isomorphism. Also, given a form of signature $(p,q)$ I would like a generating set of the group of automorphism preserving the form.

In other words, is there an effective theory of isomorphism/automorphism of indefinite quadratic forms?